# Load .data file in Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, import

I downloaded a dataset of [Blood Transfusion Service Center Data Set](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Blood+Transfusion+Service+Center)  from UCI machine learning repository. The two files are
1- transfusion.data
2- transfusion.names

How can a beginner load both these files in python ?

Comment: Hi! From a quick look at the files, it seems they are simply text files. You can inspect them with any text editor. The transfusion.data seems to be in the [CSV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) format. There are many tutorials on how to load CSV data in Python, that should get you started.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of first downloading the file (which you could do), you could do this

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv('https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/blood-transfusion/transfusion.data')
```

and

```
data = pd.read_csv('https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/blood-transfusion/transfusion.names')
```

(If you DO choose to download), use the same method but give the path to the file.)

[image]

Comment: *“Don't download them directly to your folder”* — Why not? Is it against your religion?

Comment: No....it was just a suggestion that might save time and uneccesary steps. But for the sake of argument, I'll edit.